# Assigning the value to a column based on a calculation on the go

Tags: apache-spark-sql, pyspark

Assigning the value based on a calculation on the go

I am creating a column `C_ABC` if `first.record.item = 1` then (openamt - closeamt)
if not(C_ABC+openamt)

Below code doesn't function as `C_ABC` is created on the go.
It's a bit complicated. How do we fix it?

```
df.withColumn('row',f.row_number().over(window))\
  .withColumn('C_ABC',f.when(f.col('row')==1,f.col('openammt') - f.col('closeammt')).otherwise(f.col('C_ABC')+f.col('openammt')))
```

Comment: In the otherwise part, are you referrring to previous value of that column? If possible update question with sample input and output

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you're trying to access previous row in your computation, like `C_ABC[row2]` would have value of `C_ABC[row1] + openammt`?

If so, take a closer look into `lag` function (for instance, here - https://medium.com/@aiiflo/apache-spark-window-functions-sort-lead-lag-rank-trend-analysis-46b2699fe817). You would probably need to add a separate column though, something like `c_abc_previous`